# Chaining multiple array methods in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to chain multiple methods in Array.

Original array:

```
this.array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

Clone:

```
this.array.slice(0);
```

Change the first element

```
this.array.splice(0, 0, 10);
```

> Running these individually works.

Combining both:

```
this.array.slice(0).splice(0, 0, 10);
```

> This doesnot work. Why?

Comment: Combining works. But you don't store the result of [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) invocation, so you can't see it.

Comment: @hindmost I see. Is there a way to have `splice` run on cloned instance without creating additional arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `this.array.splice(0, 0, 10);` will return a new array(containing the removed elements - in this case an empty array since no element is removed) not the source array on which it was called on.

In your case you are using a clone of the original array, so you are loosing the reference to the cloned instance.

So `this.array.slice(0)` will return a clone on which the `.splice(0, 0, 10)` is performed(it will update the cloned object) but the `splice` operation will return a new array(with removed objects) not the cloned instance so we looses reference to it

So the solution is to use a temp reference like

```
var tmp = this.array.slice(0);
tmp.splice(0, 0, 10)
```

Comment: array.slice is cloning the original array. Shouldn't splice execute on cloned array? How do you keep reference to cloned instance? By creating a temporary array?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the second `splice` will operate on the return value of the first, and return value of `array.splice()` is a new array containing the elements that have been removed from the original array.

In short, `array.splice()` is not suitable for chaining in this way.